# Regex and decimal format

Tags: regex

I want to do regular expression, where I want to check the correct pattern of decimal format with decimal comma.

Examples of correct values are:

```
1,23
123456,1
123.456,78
1
12345
123.456
```

What I have already is:

```
^((\d(\d)*|((\d){1,3}(.\d{3})*))(\,\d{1,2})?)?$
```

When I tested my code I found out that source `23,000` matches (which it shouldn't) and `1223,000` doesn't match (which is correct).

Why it happens that in some cases it finds 3 digits after comma as a match?

Comment: Why should it not match `23,000`? Too many digits after the comma?

Comment: Could you clarify the validation goal?

Comment: There is an unescaped dot in your regex, that should probably escaped. It also seems overcomplicated.

Comment: It is feature request I have to do for matching amount. There have to be 2 digits after comma.

Comment: Not answering the question, but a couple of tips... `\d(\d)*` could be rewritten as `\d+` (`+` mean 1 or more). And do you really need so many capture groups? For instance `(\d){1,3}` could simply be `\d{1,3}`. (Edit: as @Sebastian rightly spots, you haven't escaped the `.` character, which will match any character, when `\.` will match the full-stop character... oh, and you don't need to escape `,`)

Comment: @SebastianProske, it might be it. I just have to do some more tests. But why it makes differnet with four digits before comma and two digits before comam?

Comment: @freefaller, thanks for your advice. I took it into account.

Comment: @srnjak Could you please verify: You are using `.` as thousand separator and `,` as decimal separator. Numbers can contain up to 2 decimal places. Is the integer part optional (e.g. is `,12` a valid number)?

Comment: @SebastianProske, no integer part is not optional. But it might be `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first here is how I would check your number format:

```
^(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*)(?:,\d{1,2})?$
```

- `(?:pattern)` is a non-capturing group, you should use it to group things, that you don't actually need to capture.
- `\d+` matches one or more digits
- `\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*` matches 1 to 3 digits, followed by dot and 3 digits one or more times
- `(?:,\d{1,2})?` matches a comma followed by one or two digits, optional

See https://regex101.com/r/XrLpXR/1

But your actual question was why `23,000` was matched by your pattern and `1234,000` wasn't. First let's reduce your regex to the parts that were actually involved in the match:

```
^\d{1,3}(.\d{3})*$
```

So match 1 to 3 digits, then any character (note the unescaped dot) and exactly 3 digits, zero or more times.

`23,000` matches 2 digits, then comma (any character), then 3 digits
`1234,000` can't match `1234` with 3 digits and can't match the `4` with the dot, as a comma follows.